# Netbeans. "Entiry classes from database" and Postgresql domains

Tags: postgresql, netbeans, dns

I am trying to create entity classes form database with Netbeans wizard "Entiry classes from database". But if the field type in database table is an a custom domain the type of field is set to "Serializable", but it should be String or Integer. 
Because domains are just wrappers around "normal" Postgresql datatypes.
And if my table contains custom domain "DESCRIPTION" then NetBeans crashes with null pointer exception.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a netbeans bug but you didn't mention which version of postgresql and if your jdbc driver matched the version you are running. That *might* fix it.

Comment: I am using Postgresql 8.3, 
Netbeans 6.9, 
JDBC 4 for postgresql 8.4 (we need 8.4 version for COPY support)